# Render string to HTML format - YUI

Tags: html, jsp, dom, yui

I'm having an issue of converting a string to HTML. I'm using **YUI** by the way.

> var mymessage = 'Click me!!!'
>
> Y.all('#mydiv').setHTML(mymessage);

It outputs it as string not as a HTML format. 
Does anyone know what to do to fix this one.

Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

`setHTML()` passes the data to `innerHTML` as HTML.

```
Y.one("#mydiv").setHTML("<h1>Hello</h1>");

// <div id="mydiv"><h1>Hello</h1></div>
```

It means you need to escape HTML by using `Y.Escape.html()` if needed.

```
Y.one("#mydiv").setHTML(Y.Escape.html("<h1>Hello</h1>"));

// <div id="mydiv">&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;</div>
```

You're also able to use `set("text", data)` if you want to set data as the text.

```
Y.one("#mydiv").set("text", "<h1>Hello</h1>");

// <div id="mydiv">&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="mydiv">hello</div>
<div class="mydiv">hello</div>
<div class="mydiv">hello</div>
<div class="mydiv">hello</div>



 YUI().use('node', 'event', function (Y) {
      var mymessage = 'Click me!!!';
       Y.all('.mydiv').setContent('<h1>'+mymessage+'</h1>');
   });
```

Comment: You should use setContent as setHTML will not work in Internet Explorer browsers. Also you can add your desired html tag as per above example.

Comment: `setContent()` is deprecated. Use `setHTML()` instead. https://github.com/yui/yui3/pull/1183

Comment: Thanks Okuryu for updating.